# RSA encrypting without der file

Tags: ios, encryption

I'm trying to do RSA encryption with a static library that can't include an app bundle, which means I can't include a public_key.der file.

As a result, I'm trying to hardcode the .der file info into a byte array in the RSA class and generate the encryption key from that, however whenever I call `SecCertificateCreateWithData` I get a `nil` result.

Byte array:

```
const char bytes[] = "3082 02b0 3082 0219 a003 0201 0202 0900 f4da 4db7 a151 5877 300d 0609 2a86 4886 f70d 0101...9aa2";
```

And then I create NSData from that and try and create a cert:

```
NSData *publicKeyFileContent = [NSData dataWithBytes:bytes length:sizeof(bytes)];
    if (publicKeyFileContent == nil) {
        NSLog(@"%s Could not read public key", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
        return nil;
    }
    certificate = SecCertificateCreateWithData(kCFAllocatorDefault, ( __bridge CFDataRef)publicKeyFileContent);
    if (certificate == nil) {
        NSLog(@"%s Could not generate certificate", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
        return nil;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bytes you're using are a human-readable representation of the key, not the key itself.

The correct key data would look like:

```
const char bytes[] = {
    0x30, 0x82, 0x02, 0xb0, 0x30, 0x82, 0x02, 0x19, ...
};
```

(Compare the first bytes in the string representation you've got, `3082 02b0 3082 0219`.)